# How to prove that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum ^{n}_{i=1}i^{3}=\frac {n^{2}(n+1)^{2}}{4}$?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

Use mathematical induction to prove that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\sum ^{n}_{i=1}i^{3}=\dfrac {n^{2}(n+1)^{2}}{4}$$

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^3 &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3 + (n+1)^2 \stackrel{\rm(IH)}{=} \dfrac {n^{2}(n+1)^{2}}{4} + (n+1)^2 \\
&= \dfrac {n^{2}(n+1)^{2}+4(n+1)^2}{4}
\end{align*}$$

Is it true? What to do next?

Comment: first you need to correct the error in the second line

Comment: I think closing as a duplicate is misguided with this question. The OP is asking about his/her work, which isn't present in the linked post, and with a little direction (pointing out the error in adding $(n+1)^2$ instead of $(n+1)^3$. When questions are tagged "proof writing" and "proof verification", the point is not to point the OP to others' proofs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't forget the base case, $n = 1$: It holds.

Your inductive hypothesis is fine, but your inductive step is off.

You want: $$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^3 &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3\right) + (n+1)^{\color{blue}{\bf 3}} \stackrel{\rm(IH)}{=} \dfrac {n^{2}(n+1)^{2}}{4} + (n+1)^\color{blue}{\bf 3} \\
&= \dfrac {n^{2}(n+1)^{2}+4(n+1)^3}{4}\\
&= \frac{(n+1)^2(n^2 + 4(n+1))}{4}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)^2 (n^2 + 4n + 4)}{4}\\
& = \frac{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}{4}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: What to do after this? How to write description?

Comment: $IH(1)\land(\forall n\ge1:IH(n)\implies IH(n+1))\implies\forall n\ge1:IH(n)$

Comment: @Tom What we have shown is that the proposition $P(1)$ is true, and most important, that the inductive hypothesis $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$. Therefore, by the principle of induction, the proposition is true for all $n \geq 1$. Note that the last expression is $\dfrac{(n+1)^2((n+1)+1)^2}4$ which means that $P(n+1)$ does indeed follow from the inductive hypothesis.